# How to convert reddit posts to list in dart?

Tags: json, dart, reddit

I want to get posts from Reddit API. Posts are in "children" node but each object has another object inside.

Can somebody help me write a function that convert this JSON to a list of dart objects?

Here is JSON string.

```
{
    "kind": "Listing",
    "data": {
        "after": "t3_zzzhq4",
        "dist": 2,
        "children": [
            {
                "kind": "t3",
                "data": {
                    
                    "selftext": "blablabla",
                    "author_fullname": "3xblabla",
                    "title": "moreblabla",
                    "created": 1672515982,
                    "id": "10020p0"
                }
            },
            {
                "kind": "t3",
                "data": {
                    "selftext": "blablabla",
                    "author_fullname": "3xblabla",
                    "title": "moreblabla",
                    "created": 1672515982,
                    "id": "10020p0"
                }
            }
        ],
        "before": null
    }
}
```

I tried all the tutorials on the topic of complex json parsing, but none of them met my needs. I would know how to parse simple json, but here it is deeply nested JSON, which bothers me a lot, and i cant quite grasp it. Appreciete any help.

Solution:

1. First go to j[son to dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) and paste JSON string, this generator will make you all classes needed for your JSON.
2. Then you will need to decode string:

   final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
3. And then deserialize your JSON like this:

   List postslist = list.map((i) => Post.fromJson(i['data'])).toList();

For me, it was crucial i['data']. After adding that, i could deserialize all objects that were living inside that node. Thanks everyone! Hope that someone else this will be helpful! Cheers.

Comment: Consider using a library like [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable), or [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) or a number of others. If you have used a library, please provide a [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your issue, error messages you're getting, line numbers where the error are, and what you've tried.

Comment: Hey Madushan, thanks for reply. The problem is i don't know what to try. I would know how to go about this if there were not another "data" node inside "children" list for each post, but with this type of JSON i don't have an idea what to do, and even what to try.

Comment: sorry write the code as it doesnt have such a node. then try to add it. If you still can't, share the code and possible errors etc. The answer depends on what library you use, how you're reading/parsing the data among other things. I think you're having issues with modelling the JSON, which should be somewhat of a simple issue to resolve if you provide the code you have.

Comment: Thanks Madushan, i will try it, and then i will paste code. Thanks once again.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.